# Facebook PHP SDK v5 : Read Page Public Feeds?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk, feed

*(I'm new to Facebook SDK)*

I installed Facebook PHP SDK v5 by this way:

```
# ./composer.phar require facebook/php-sdk-v4
```

Then here is my first page which gets the `User Access Token` successfully.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '<my-valid-app-id>',
    'app_secret' => '<my-valid-app-secret>',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
    'persistent_data_handler'=>'session',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper(); 
$accessToken = "";

if ( isset($_SESSION["facebook_access_token"]) ) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION["facebook_access_token"];
}

if ( $accessToken=="" ) {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.example.com/login-callback.php', []);      
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
    exit;
}

try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me', $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as: ' . $me->getName() . ' (' . $me->getId() . ')';
echo '<hr>';

// -----------------------------------------------------------------    
// --------------------- THIS WORKS UP TO HERE! --------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * GET PUBLIC FEEDS
 */
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

$session = new FacebookSession( $accessToken );

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/Google/feed?limit=5'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

print_r( $graphObject );
?>
```

(There is another page called: `login-callback.php` which also works fine; to get the `User Access Token` saved into Session.)

Now ... as mentioned with comments in above file, the whole thing works util this comment session:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------    
// --------------------- THIS WORKS UP TO HERE! --------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

It shows something like this:

```
Logged in as: Robert Walters (48650862XXXXXXX)
```

---

### Problem

But after the above certain point (as we see), i start reading the public feeds from `/Google/feed?limit=5` page.

Then the error comes:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\\FacebookSession' not found in ...
```

...............

### Questions

1. Strangely, i didn't find `FacebookSession.php` file in my SDK.
2. After that, how do i properly read the public feeds from Users & Pages?

Thanks all.

Comment: You are using outdated code - `FacebookSession` existed in v4 of the PHP SDK. Go check the documentation, it has examples for basic stuff such as this. And FYI, to read a public page’s public posts, you can also use your app access token, meaning you don’t necessarily have to have users login to your app for this.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thanks much for helping. Is there any sample or recommended codes with the best approach for this purpose please? :)

Comment: Just check the examples in the docs – even most basic ones such as “Retrieve User Profile” can show you how to make simple API requests.